# Next question about russian encoding, mssql and python

Tags: python, windows, unicode, console, pymssql

Next question about russian encoding, mssql and python.

I have this simple code:

```
import pymssql
import codecs
conn=pymssql.connect(host='localhost:1433', user='sa',  password='password', database='TvPgms')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT TOP 5 CAST( Name AS nvarchar(400) ), CONVERT(nvarchar(400), idProgram) FROM dbo.Programs')
p=cur.fetchone()
h=p[0]
d=codecs.lookup(h)
print h
conn.close()
```

I get the error: LookUp Error : Unnown Encoding: ????? ?????? ???????

I cant reed russian varchar filds from MSSQL. But when i just print string in the same code all is ok, it print me normal russian characters.
Who know how?

If I truing just print h insted of codecs.lookup  than i get no error, but it prints me ???????? ?????????

Comment: Please don't open that many similar questions. Before trying to fetch database entries, you must start from the very beginning and get `print u"абвгдежзийкл"` to work, which seems to be hard enough on Windows.

Comment: This is really an other problem. When I print u"абвгдежзийкл" it gives me абвгдежзийкл, but when i print my data from database it gives me ??????????????????????????

Comment: In the other thread you stated that it wouldn't work.

Comment: I wrote that i fixed this problem. Now it is other problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`codecs.lookup` takes an encoding name, not some random string, and you probably don't need it here anyway. I think at the moment you cannot reliably print Unicode strings from Python to the Windows console due to deep technical problems. Try writing to a file or using the `WriteConsoleW` function directly (via `ctypes`) instead.

Comment: It do not help, I tried write in file. In file I get the same question marks.

Comment: Maybe you know what type of encoding send me mssql server respond?

Comment: No, and if there are already errors when trying to work with literal strings, it doesn't matter yet.

Comment: The database server will send the encoding defined by the collation given to the table. Not sure with pymssql but when using mysqldb to connect to MySql, you can define encoding with the database adding `'?charset=utf8&use_unicode=1'` to the connection string. I guess this is probably possible also with mssql and pymssql but I don't know how.